# Generic helper method with multiple type arguments

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a WebTarget POST call that gets called several times with different parameters and different deserialization classes for each call.  So, I want to abstract the WebTarget code into a method that will simply accept the arguments, also allowing me to fail on one call without stopping the other calls.

Here is the WebTarget call as it currently is (The 3 Token.* classes listed below are inner classes of Token that also extend Token and Text is a simple wrapper class):

```
 Token[] profileLocationTokens = target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(profileLocationText)), Token.ProfileLocationToken[].class);

 Token[] profileDescriptionTokens = target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(profileDescriptionText)), Token.ProfileDescriptionToken[].class);

 Token[] statusTexttokens = target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(statusText)), Token.StatusTextToken[].class);
```

I want to create the method that looks similar to the below:

```
private Token[] execPost(WebTarget target, String content, Class tokenClass) {
    try {
        return target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(content)), tokenClass);
    } catch (javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException bre) {
            LOG.error(bre.getMessage());
}
```

I know I need to make the Class generic and somehow or other pass in the type, however I have tried it every which way I can think of and each time I get compile-time "Inference variable has incompatible bounds" errors.  Another issue that seems to be messing me up here is that I am passing in the Class of the subclass (e.g. Token.ProfileLocationToken) for deserialization and referring to the results as the Superclass, so I was trying to create bounded types...also unsuccessfully.

I'm not using Generics anywhere else in the class; the type definition would come from the calling method in the same class.

If anyone could help by showing me how to create that method properly so it works the way I'd like it to, I would appreciate it.

**EDIT 1** Per request, below are a couple of the ways I tried it.  Note, I get my attempts are all over the place, I'm not experienced working with Generics yet.  I also have the issue of trying to force it into an array of my class-type.

I started out with the following method as my first try:

```
private <T extends Token>Token[] execPost(WebTarget target, String content, T tokenClass) {
    try {
        return target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(content)), tokenClass);
    } catch (javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException bre) {
        LOG.error(bre.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With the following error:

```
method javax.ws.rs.client.SyncInvoker.<T>post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<?>,java.lang.Class<T>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T 
   (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>))
method javax.ws.rs.client.SyncInvoker.<T>post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<?>,javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType<T>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType<T>))
```

---

I also tried having it return T and then just refer to it as Token[] when I assign the returned array:

```
private <T extends Token>T[] execPost(WebTarget target, String content, Class<T> tokenClass) {
    try {
        return target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(content)), tokenClass);
    } catch (javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException bre) {
        LOG.error(bre.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With the following compiler error:

```
equality constraints: T
    upper bounds: T[],java.lang.Object
```

While the compiler error is less descriptive, Netbeans says the following:

```
inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: T#2
    upper bounds: T#2[],Object
where T#1, T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>post(Entity<?>,Class<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Token declared in method <T#2>execPost(WebTarget,String,Class<T#2>)
```

Comment: Show an example of what you tried and the exact error message so that we can explain exactly what is wrong and how you can fix it.

Comment: Another thing to consider is separate URLs.  Distinguish different flavors by binding them to URLs that make the contract and intent clearer.

Comment: `Token[].class` is not superclass of `Token.StatusTextToken[].class` because they are arrays

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, I can declare Token[] tokenArr with an instantiation of Token.StatusTextToken[1], doesn't the same relationship apply to the Class objects?  Either way, the .post calls work just fine without abstracting it to a method.

Comment: @Brooks which is returning type of `.post()` in runtime? I bet that `Token[]`, not `Token.WhicheverSybtype[]`. It just creates `Token[]` array and puts subclassed instances there. So returning type of your method also should be `Token[]`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, it should be returning type Token.Subtype[] because i'm passing in the subtype for .post to use to deserialize the json coming back from the HTTP POST request.  It currently works (without the method implementation).  The subtype's constructor merely passes a value up to the Superclass and I have verified that value is being passed for each of the different subtypes, thus the subtypes are being instantiated.

Comment: @Brooks it should be or it is? *Values* can be of subtype classes, *array itself* cannot. Arrays are not generic in Java.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, As far as I can tell, it is.  The following code is confirmed to work.  Token[] statusTexttokens = target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(statusText)), Token.StatusTextToken[].class);  The inheritance works just fine, though your point may have implications for the use of generics, but even then my typing the argument AND return-type as T still doesn't work.

Comment: Why can't you use `<T extends Token> Token[] execPost(... Class<T> tokenClass)`?

Comment: It works, because it returns `Token[]`, and no conflict occur.

Comment: Sorry, but you still don't understand that `Token.Subclass[]` *is not* sublass of `Token[]`, the same as `String[]` is not subclass of `CharSequence[]` nor even subclass of `Object[]`, regardless of that `String[]` can hold `CharSequence` instances, and `Object[]` can hold `String`s. The only superclass of those three is `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may or may not be elegant, this method works:

```
private <T extends Token> T[] execPost(WebTarget target, String content, Class<T[]> tokenClass) {
    T[] arr = null;
    try {
        arr = target.request().post(Entity.json(new Text(content)), tokenClass);
    } catch (javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException bre) {
        LOG.error(bre.getMessage());
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Here is the call to the above method:

```
Token[] profileLocationTokens = execPost(target, profileLocationText, Token.ProfileLocationToken[].class);
Token[] statusTextTokens = execPost(target, statusText, Token.StatusTextToken[].class);
Token[] profileDescriptionTokens = execPost(target, profileDescriptionText, Token.ProfileDescriptionToken[].class);
```

There was question in the comments above as to whether or not the elements in the array returned by the newly created method are really instances of Token.Subclass or just of Token.  I tested the returned array's as follows:

```
if (statusTextTokens.length != 0 && statusTextTokens[0] instanceof Token.StatusTextToken) {
    LOG.info("Instance of StatusTextToken");
}

if (profileLocationTokens.length != 0 && profileLocationTokens[0] instanceof Token.ProfileLocationToken) {
    LOG.info("Instance of ProfileLocationToken");
}

if (profileDescriptionTokens.length != 0 && profileDescriptionTokens[0] instanceof Token.ProfileDescriptionToken) {
    LOG.info("Instance of ProfileDescriptionToken");
}
```

In each case, the log output was generated.

Answer (score 1):

The signature could be

```
private <T extends Token> T[] execPost(WebTarget target, String content, Class<T> tokenClass) {
```

Please note that in this case you pass the type in the arrays, not the array type.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (see my Edit to the original post)